# running the same selenium test on a varying list of urls

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm debugging a big site, and I want to make sure a certain element doesn't appear in any of the pages of the site.

I want to use selenium for that, but I'm completely new to it. I managed to create my test for a specific page easily with the FF addon, but I don't want to repeat the process for each page.

My question is, is there a way to make the test run on all the pages of the site, or alternatively, provide selenium with a list of urls against which to run the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:
http://saucelabs.com/blog/index.php/2011/01/selenium-resources-for-newbs-data-driven-testing-with-ide-xml/

so you will end up with a loop:

```
loadTestData    | file:///listofURLs.xml

while | !testdata.EOF()

nextTestData |

open | ${variableURL}

verifyTextPresent | sometext

verifyTextPresent | sometext

endWhile |
```